# How can I link a subdomain in 1and1 with a OVH hosting?

Tags: dns, subdomain, vps, 1and1

I have bought a domain (`example.com`) in 1and1 where I have my main website, this website is hosted in 1and1.

On the other hand I have a VPS server hosted in [OVH](https://www.ovh.com/). And I have Odoo installed in that server.

What I want to do is to map a subdomain that I've created in 1and1. So when I load `subdomain.example.com` I want to load Odoo. But I can't change the DNS's of the subdomain, instead of this I must use the **"A record"** in order to make the forwarding.

**What I have done:**

1. I create a domain `example.com` in 1and1
2. I create a subdomain `subdomain.example.com` in 1and1
3. I registered my subdomain in OVH
4. I read "A record" in the OVH subdomain registration and I copied it to the 1and1 subdomain configuration

Now, when I load my subdomain it redirects to a webmail page of OVH

Which are the next steps I should follow in order to load Odoo in that subdomain?

**NOTE:** I can use NginX as reverse proxy in the VPS server and I can change the port where Odoo is executed

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by *instead of this I must use the "A record" in order to make the forwarding*. A records only associate a domain name to an IP address. Nothing more. Can you explain what you mean so that we understand?? Cheers!!

Comment: We would really need more information. The next step is to determine where things diverge from the expectation. If you really do have `subdomain.example.com` setup as an A record for the IP address give by OVH, and if OVH really is listening on that IP address and port 80, assuming you're using the standard web port, for `subdomain.example.com`, and that uses the docroot for your software, then you should see that software. So, one of those things is likely not true.

Comment: Thanks @closetnoc, you opened my eyes. I wrote the IP adress of the VPS in the "A record" directly and everything is working. I thought it was more complex

Comment: I am glad you got it! Cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to create a subdomain in OVH. You onle have to create the "A record" in the 1and1 subdomain, pointing to the VPS IP. That should be enough